# INDEX MATCH to return value that is not blank

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet with years across the top and months down the side and data in the middle. I would like to use INDEX MATCH to get the data, but it is returning blank cells. It looks something like this:

```
__A__  __B__  __C__  __D__
Year    2001   2002   2003
Jan     1000   2000
Feb     1000   2000   8000
Jan                   8000
```

Now it is returning blank when I lookup `Jan` in row and `2003` in column.

It is going from different sheets, but it looks somewhat like this:

```
=INDEX($1:$948576,MATCH($B171,$B:$B,0),MATCH(C$1,$1:$1,0))
```

There will only be one data point for Jan 2003, so if I could just get it to ignore the blanks it would work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please place your current formula to better assist you in this issue?

Comment: Of course its giving you blank because that is the first result that matches Jan 2003. Are the months down the columns not unique? What happens if there are multiple values that meet that consideration? Do you want the sum returned?

Comment: It is going from different sheets, but it looks somwhat like this =INDEX($1:$948576,MATCH($B171,$B:$B,0),MATCH(C$1,$1:$1,0))

Comment: And there will not be multiple vales - sorry should have made that clear.  There will only be one data point for Jan 2003, so if I could just get it to ignore the blanks it would work.

Comment: Something like this should work for you (change sheetname to suit): `=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B:$B,$B171,INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$948576,0,MATCH(C$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)))`

Comment: Given the further information I think your original formula is working as intended. I think the issue is that you need to curate your data so that there are no duplicate data points. If the intersection of Jan and 2003 is an empty cell then your formula returning `0` is correct. Unless I'm still misunderstand the context.

Comment: The formula would work normally, but I need to modify it to ignore the first blank.  Is that possible?

Comment: tigeravatar's solution would work for this as it would sum any blank value as a zero but if there are any other non-blank duplicate data points it would add them ALL together. I'm still confused though as you stated that there would be no multiple data points. Did you mean that there might be a duplicate blank but only 1 with an actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *know* you want the data from the fourth (e.g. *2003*) column, the formula to ignore blanks is fairly straightforward.

```
=INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9999)/((A$1:A$9999="Jan")*SIGN(LEN(D$1:D$9999))), 1))
```

However, if 2003 is in a cell and you have to use it to determine which column to retrieve, it gets a little more complicated.

[image: Non-blank lookup with multiples]

The standard formula¹ in G5 is,

```
=INDEX($A:$D, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9999)/(($A$1:$A$9999=G$2)*SIGN(LEN(INDEX($A$1:$D$9999, 0, MATCH($F5,$1:$1, 0))))), 1), MATCH($F5,$1:$1,0))
```

If there are some columns where retrieving a blank in unavoidable, the the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can be used to provide some error control.

You may also be interested in adapting the VBA found in [Find first non-blank cell for each column from rows that match lookup to merge duplicate matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639400/find-first-non-blank-cell-for-each-column-from-rows-that-match-lookup-to-merge-d/32640672#32640672) to repair and collate your data.

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>